# PHP profiling in VS Code is not showing call times

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, kcachegrind, xdebug-profiler

I'm using VS Code and particularly the "PHP" extension to open cachegrind files that I have xdebug generating. When I open the file in Qcachegrind, it shows everything correctly including call times. But opening the profile file in VS Code shows all call times as "0.00ms". Why could this be?

Comment: That sounds odd, can you share a couple of dozen lines from your cachegrind file? How old is your VS Code?

Comment: My VS Code tends to keep itself up to date, so should be the latest. It's 1.77.3. Here's some of my cachegrind file:
`version: 1
creator: xdebug 2.8.1 (PHP 7.4.0-dev)
cmd: <redacted>\organisations.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time Memory

fl=(1) php:internal
fn=(1) php::trim
3 1 0

fl=(1)
fn=(2) php::session_start
2 249 6480

fl=(1)
fn=(3) php::ob_start
3 1 16664

fl=(1)
fn=(4) php::error_reporting
4 0 408

fl=(2) <redacted>includes\classes\database.class.php
fn=(5) require_once::<redacted>includes\classes\database.class.php
1 2 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Xdebug version is no longer supported. [Only Xdebug 3 is](https://xdebug.org/docs/compat#versions). I can't see anything wrong with your cachegrind file (mostly, because it's all squished in one line), so I would recommend you file a bug report with the VS Code PHP Plugin people: https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the smushed-together cachegrind file! I'll look at getting everything up to date rather than lodging bugs for unsupported versions.